# Is there a way to manage 2 types of currencies rate for one coin in ODOO?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Is there a way to manage 2 types of currencies rate for one coin in ODOO?

Like the USD currency for sale and USD currency for purchase, for some specifics transactions I use USD currency for sale or USD currency for purchase, how can I use it without update every moment the USD rate? For more details: My base currency rate is PEN, for sale 1USD = 3.39PEN, and for purchase 1USD = 3.36PEN.

I've tried adding a new column to rates for USD, rate2, and add some changes in 'account.voucher' but despite my efforts sometimes choose 'rate' over my 'rate2', I can't follow all the operations made by Odoo, How can I do it? Thans for all your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of box you don't have this feature to manage two different types of rates as functionally ot becomes challenging to choose which one. Rather I would use trick here create one more usd current with different rates and do multi-currenncy transaction.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo: unfortunately you have to implement this feature.

Comment: But what do you thik It would be the impact on contability, using one more usd currency?

Comment: @JuanSalcedo: Their won't be any big issue as all transaction on database are stored in base currency with other currecy rate used at that time. so nothing to worry, but their could be situation some times when you will do invoice and payment indifferent currency then you can use extra journal to record difference amount  which you can balance at end of period.

Comment: Yes its what I'm trying now, using extra journals, well thanks for your answer @shadowsjedi I apreciate it a lot.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo : Help up voting odoo forum on stack exchange : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93260/odoo-openerp/